# Can threading.Event's set() or clear() function fail in any case

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

Is there any case where `threading.Event`'s `set()` or `clear()` can fail, viz. calling `set()` again without `clear()`, etc.

Right now I am adding `try-except` block around all `set()` and `clear()` calls.

In [Python27 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#event-objects), this is not specified specifically.

I asked this because intuitively it doesn't make sense to raise exception if you set a already set boolean flag or clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: No.

The truthiness of `Event` is a simple boolean, guarded by a lock.

```
class Event:
    """Class implementing event objects.

    Events manage a flag that can be set to true with the set() method and reset
    to false with the clear() method. The wait() method blocks until the flag is
    true.  The flag is initially false.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._cond = Condition(Lock())
        self._flag = False
```

Setting and clearing simply gets the lock and sets the value. There is no toggling involved, nor is the previous value checked. No exception is thrown explicitly - you can of course get generic exceptions such as `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it, it worked fine. But I am from C background, so I was thinking if this is always true, i.e. in all platform, etc.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild In general, Python opts for the lowest common denominator. For example, `signal`s are only ever handled by the main thread, even if the underlying platform would allow otherwise. It's not a real rule, but for core modules such as `threading`, you can bet someone would have complained about inconsistencies across platforms.